# How to use for-loop in Java to print out an image that made by symbols?

Tags: java, for-loop

I got stuck on making the symbols at the end of the second line using for-loop,I had tried couple times and still not work. Can someone tell me where I did wrong?

```
   ////////////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ 
   ////////////********
   ////////**************** 
   ////************************
   ********************************
```

And it suppose to be look like this:

```
   ////////////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ 
   ////////////********\\\\\\\\\\\\ 
   ////////****************\\\\\\\\ 
   ////************************\\\\ 
   ********************************
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main (String [] args){

    for (int lineOne=1; lineOne<=16; lineOne += 2){
        System.out.print("//");
    }
    for (int lineOne=1; lineOne<=32; lineOne += 2){
        System.out.print("\\");
    }
    System.out.println("");

    for (int a=8; a<=32; a += 8)
    {
        for (int b=12; b < (28 - a / 2); b +=2)
        {
            System.out.print("//");
        }
        for (int c=0; c<a; c++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");            
    }   
}
```

Comment: Didn't think this one through, did you.

Comment: After you print your `*`s, you don't print any `\ ` ?

Comment: If you have done it so far, you CAN make it.. Have patience and apply your logic.

Comment: i printed a new line at the end

Comment: Try to do your homework, on your own.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I missed two tab characters. You missed that, too. To claim I made it worse shows ineptitude on your part. Not to mention that you reverted and then went and made a ton of changes of your own. God forbid you're ever let near a source code repository.

Comment: @PP. [look at your revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19577191/2) - it's broken. Look at the current revision. Fixed.

Comment: @Blorgbeard YOU look at the revisions, you clearly didn't. But I get it now, you're a c# developer. All makes sense now.

Comment: @Blorgbeard meh if you want to cry about it go take a hike up Rangitoto.

Comment: @pp. follow the link. It's **broken**. I'm not talking about brace style. I actually use K&R style in my code, but I left OP's style alone.

Comment: @PP. congratulations, you can name a landmark in my city. I hope you don't work here if you think [this](http://i.imgur.com/NNrLSof.png) is properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you just did not print it at all.

It should work fine:

```
    for (int lineOne=1; lineOne<=16; lineOne += 2){
    System.out.print("//");
                                                 }
    for (int lineOne1=1; lineOne1<=32; lineOne1 += 2){
    System.out.print("\\");
       }
    System.out.println("");
    for (int a=8; a<=32; a += 8)
      {
    for (int b=12; b < 28-a/2; b +=2)
    {
        System.out.print("//");
    }
    for (int c=0; c<a; c++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");

    }

    // this prints your "\\"
    for(int k = 0;k<16-a/2;k++) 
    {
     System.out.print("\\");   
    }

    System.out.println(" ");

}
```

Comment: do you know how to make it into 4 or 3 for-loops?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `"\\"` is actually just a single backslash, escaped. That's why you had to print 32 `"\\"`s to balance out the 16 `"//"`s. You probably meant to print out 16 `"\\\\"`s.

Secondly you had no code to print backslashes after the first line. So I suggest you add some code to handle this.

Thirdly your source code was a mix of tabs and space indentation. Which may have confused you when reviewing the logic flow of your own program. Consistent indenting might really assist you here.

Comment: i did print 32 "\\" s and 16 "//"s

Comment: after 30 mins i finally got it. Be grateful of your advice。